# Best way to open a file on client's computer

Tags: java, file, applet, client

I am writing a web based version control system and when a user checks out a code file it is automatically copied to a shared network folder that they have access to. I would then like to automatically open that file on their computer with whatever their default program is for that file type. I do not want the user to have to download and then open the file as it needs to all be automated.

I tried writing a java applet but am hitting some road blocks and before I go further would like to know what people think would be the easiest or best way of implementing this functionality. I would prefer the user to not have to install a piece of software prior to using the system. That was my purpose in initially trying an applet.

I appreciate any advice or recommendations.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to accomplish, I believe this sort of thing can be done fairly easily with PHP depending on exactly what you want to do, or you might want to try web start instead of an applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with writing a client-side protocol handler that I could invoke by redirecting the browser to "myprotocol:data". Unfortunately it involves some client-side setup as they need the protocol handler but it is very simple, basic, and lightweight as well as event driven so no listener is necessary.